How to draw a partial border around a circle, based on a percentage, in jetpack compose?
This is the kind of effect I want:

How much of the border is colored is dynamic.
(I am adding the css code because stack overflow demands 220 characters)
.sk-progress {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  /* background-color: red; */
}
.sk-progress svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
.sk-progress svg circle {
  fill: var(--bg-color);
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: var(--main-color-1);
  stroke-dasharray: 427;
  stroke-dashoffset: 427;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
@keyframes progress {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--target);
  }
}


Found the answer:
CircularProgressIndicator(
    progress = { currentProgress },
    modifier = Modifier.width(64.dp),
    color = color,
    trackColor = Color.Blue,
)

For more info, check https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/components/progress.

Since you already seem to be using SVG, you may be looking for Arc paths.
You could overlay an arc over the circle and control its value with JS.


const arcPath = document.querySelector('#arc-path')

function setValue(v) {
  const r = 40
  const arcEnd = {
    x: 50 + r * Math.sin(2*Math.PI * v),
    y: 50 - r * Math.cos(2*Math.PI * v),
  }
  const largeArc = v % 1 > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
  arcPath.setAttribute('d', `M 50 10 A 40 40 0 ${largeArc} 1 ${arcEnd.x} ${arcEnd.y}`)
}

(function animate() {
  setValue(Date.now() / 5000)
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
})()
<svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#F8F5FE"/>
  <path id="arc-path" stroke="#6D34FD" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" />
</svg>




Looks like you can actually do this mostly in CSS, just have to add some math.


const arcPath = document.querySelector('.arc-path')

function setValue(v) {
  arcPath.style.setProperty('--target', v % 1)
}

(function animate() {
  setValue(Date.now() / 5000)
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
})()
svg circle.arc-path {
  --target: 0;
  --radius: 40;
  --circ: calc(2 * pi * var(--radius));
  --dash-len: calc(var(--target) * var(--circ));
  /* rotate the circle so the stroke starts at the top */
  transform: translate(50px, 50px) rotate(-90deg) translate(-50px, -50px);
  /* specify painted and unpainted parts */
  stroke-dasharray: var(--dash-len) calc(var(--circ) - var(--dash-len));
}
<svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle class="arc-path" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#6D34FD" fill="#F8F5FE" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>



